# Kmalloc Alignment

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kmalloc

Lets say I allocate with kmalloc an array of uint64_t (and lets assume the size of the array is 32kB). I have the following questions :

1) Is the array guaranteed to be page aligned ?
2) Is the array guaranteed to be cache / block aligned ?
3) Is there no guarantee at all ?

When I allocate the array , and i use virt_to_phys to get the physical address of the array i am gettign physical addresses like 00000040142d5c00 and virtual addresses like fffffe07df400000

Is there any chance that i will end up with alignment smaller than uint64_t , lets say 4 byte alignment or not ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment defined by preprocessor constant `ARCH_KMALLOC_MINALIGN`,

it was calculeted like this:

```
#if defined(ARCH_DMA_MINALIGN) && ARCH_DMA_MINALIGN > 8
#define ARCH_KMALLOC_MINALIGN ARCH_DMA_MINALIGN
#define KMALLOC_MIN_SIZE ARCH_DMA_MINALIGN
#define KMALLOC_SHIFT_LOW ilog2(ARCH_DMA_MINALIGN)
#else
#define ARCH_KMALLOC_MINALIGN __alignof__(unsigned long long)
#endif
```

So in theory `__alignof__(unsigned long long)` may return some smaller then 8
on some exotic case,
but in practice  `__alignof__(unsigned long long)` >= 8, and so ARCH_KMALLOC_MINALIGN would be >= 8.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sir !!! The fact that i am constantly getting physical addresses like 0x00000040142d5c00 you think is due to the fact that my system has lots of memory (8 gB) and it is after a reboot so there is little to none fragmentation ?

Comment: @XII I suppose most memory allocation happens during boot, almost all other cases uses memory pools (already allocated memory/memory allocated by big chunks), plus many need virtual memory, not physical, so they use `vmalloc` so it is big probability to get the same address after `kmalloc`.

Comment: So, does this mean that kmalloc does not guarantee page/cacheline alignment? Is there another function that needs to be called before kmalloc to ensure cache/page alignment?

Comment: @szs It was fixed in recent kernels, see https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.15-rc7&id=59bb47985c1db229ccff8c5deebecd54fc77d2a9