# DMA Engine Timeout and DMA Memory Mapping

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, xilinx, dma

I am trying to use a Linux DMA driver. Currently, when I send the transaction out and begin waiting, my request times out. I believe this has to do with the way I am setting up my buffers when I am performing DMA Mapping.

```
char *src_dma_buffer = kmalloc(dma_length, GFP_KERNEL);
char *dest_dma_buffer = kzalloc(dma_length, GFP_KERNEL);

tx_dma_handle = dma_map_single(tx_chan->device->dev, src_dma_buffer, dma_length, DMA_TO_DEVICE);    
rx_dma_handle = dma_map_single(rx_chan->device->dev, dest_dma_buffer, dma_length, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

In Xilinx's DMA driver, they take special care to look at memory alignment. In particular, they use a property of the dma_chan->dma_device called copy_align.

> - @copy_align: alignment shift for memcpy operations

```
const int dma_length = 16*1024;
len = dmatest_random() % test_buf_size + 1;
len = (len >> align) << align;
if (!len)
    len = 1 << align;
src_off = dmatest_random() % (test_buf_size - len + 1);
dst_off = dmatest_random() % (test_buf_size - len + 1);

src_off = (src_off >> align) << align;
dst_off = (dst_off >> align) << align;
```

It looks like that original address is totally random from dmatest_random(). Not sure what can be said/what guarentees can be made about that memory.

```
static unsigned long dmatest_random(void)
{
    unsigned long buf;

    get_random_bytes(&buf, sizeof(buf));
    return buf;
}
```

They then use these offsets to set up their source and destination buffers for DMA.

```
u8 *buf = thread->srcs[i] + src_off;

dma_srcs[i] = dma_map_single(tx_dev->dev, buf, len, DMA_MEM_TO_DEV);
```

I am very confused as to what this does. My only guess is that it will page align the beginning of the source and destination buffers in virtual memory.

Looking at the way I set up my buffers with kmalloc and kzalloc, do I have any guarantee that my buffers start at page boundaries? Am I right in that I need my buffers to start at page boundaries?

The source code to the Xilinx DMA test driver is here: https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/drivers/dma/xilinx/axidmatest.c

You can find the high level description of the problem I am trying to solve here: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/AXI-DMA-Drivers-for-Kernel-v-4-9-PetaLinux-2017-3/td-p/828917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255742/kmalloc-alignment) seems that you don't have any guarantee that your memory allocation will start at the beginning of a frame page. However, [this other link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html) can be helpful, where it is explained alloc_pages, that maybe fit better with what you need.

In regarding with the alignment of the memory to be used in DMA transactions, into [this link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) we can read the following:

> ## What memory is DMA'able?
>
> The first piece of information you must know is what kernel memory can
>   be used with the DMA mapping facilities.  There has been an unwritten
>   set of rules regarding this, and this text is an attempt to finally
>   write them down.
>
> If you acquired your memory via the page allocator
>   (i.e. __get_free_page*()) or the generic memory allocators
>   (i.e. kmalloc() or kmem_cache_alloc()) then you may DMA to/from
>   that memory using the addresses returned from those routines.
>
> This means specifically that you may *not* use the memory/addresses
>   returned from vmalloc() for DMA.  It is possible to DMA to the
>   *underlying* memory mapped into a vmalloc() area, but this requires
>   walking page tables to get the physical addresses, and then
>   translating each of those pages back to a kernel address using
>   something like __va().  [ EDIT: Update this when we integrate
>   Gerd Knorr's generic code which does this. ]
>
> This rule also means that you may use neither kernel image addresses
>   (items in data/text/bss segments), nor module image addresses, nor
>   stack addresses for DMA.  These could all be mapped somewhere entirely
>   different than the rest of physical memory.  Even if those classes of
>   memory could physically work with DMA, you'd need to ensure the I/O
>   buffers were cacheline-aligned.  Without that, you'd see cacheline
>   sharing problems (data corruption) on CPUs with DMA-incoherent caches.
>   (The CPU could write to one word, DMA would write to a different one
>   in the same cache line, and one of them could be overwritten.)
>
> Also, this means that you cannot take the return of a kmap()
>   call and DMA to/from that.  This is similar to vmalloc().
>
> What about block I/O and networking buffers?  The block I/O and
>   networking subsystems make sure that the buffers they use are valid
>   for you to DMA from/to.

So that, only we need the address to be aligned with cacheline-size, and we don't need to get memory aligned to frame page (it would work too, but it is not needed). In regarding with the [manual about kmalloc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html), if we specify the flag GFP_DMA we get memory suitable for DMA transactions (aligned to cacheline-size).

Comment: the real question is: does it need to start at the beginning of the page frame for DMA transactions to take place. Whether the buffers do or not is trivial until that is established

Comment: By the information into this link (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt), the memory for the DMA should be aligned with the cache-line, to avoid data corruption, so that, you don't need memory aligned with the beginning of a frame page, but yes with the cache-line. In a core i7, it is 64 bytes.

Comment: I have just read the manual for kmalloc, based into the above information, if you use kmalloc with the flag GFP_DMA, the returned address should be suitable for DMA transactions, so that, in such scenario, the returned address is aligned with cacheline-size that is the only thing to consider based into the information above.

Comment: I read that too. I just wonder why Xilinx saw the need to do what appears to be page alignment in their driver. It looks like they use kmalloc to initialize their source and destination buffers, but then they adjust the pointers. All software I have written uses GFP_KERNEL for allocation. It looks like I had a scatter gather DMA port on the Xilinx AXI DMA core that might be affecting things. I have removed it and am rebuilding the software